# Using XPages Toolkit Domino Storage Service to load a tree of objects into Java Objects

Tags: xpages

I'm building an application that allows user to register for a particular session for a particular course.

The data is structured like a tree, i.e. one course can have many sessions who can have many registrations.

I've built up views with unique IDs for each object, including the id of the parent object.

What I'm now trying to do is setting up my XPage so that all the data gets loaded into memory, so that I can access all the data directly through the java objects instead of binding directly to the views (which is just ugly).

I'm thinking of building the objects like this:

```
public class ApplicationBean implements Serializable {

private Set<Course> courses;

public void addCourse(Course input){};

    public void initialize {
      - load all courses, sessionns, registrations from flat Notes Views
      - updates 
};
}

 public class Course implements Serializable {
 private Set<Session> sessions;

 public void addSession(Session input){}

 }

public class Session implements Serializable {

    private Course parent;
    private Set<Registrations> registrations;
    public Course getParent(){}
    public void addRegistration(Registration input) {}

}


public class Registration implements Serializable {

    private Session parent;
    public Session getParent(){}
}
```

An example is: Show me the list of all the courses that I have registered for. I would like a list which shows:

```
registration session(from parent of registration) course (from parent of session)
```

where the rows would be filled in with

```
registration.description   registration.session.title registration.session.course.title
```

I've looked into the Domino Storage Service (DSS) from Christian Güdemann's XPages toolkit and it looks really promising; all the Database Access Object bits of the logic are automagically created. I'd like to use this but the example database just shows a simple, flat data - contacts.

I'm thinking of having some sort of applicationBean which, when first loaded, loads all three flat lists of objects into memory and then creates in a second step the linking between the objects.

What would be the best solution here? Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you want them in memory, really? you can (and should) use application bean to make more readable code, but it does not imply you need them in memory. something like WeakHashMap is better, IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You outlined the parts of the solution already:

- Design your Java class as a bean
- have properties that can be bound in EL

I wouldn't use a managed bean as long as your interaction is a single page app. I would use the bean data source that has distinct load/save events you can use. 
When you use multi pages you want to persist things between pages, there a managed bean session scope makes sense.

You could use the managed bean as a cache and still use a bean (I think officially it is called Object Data Source) data source.

Let us know how it goes

Comment: thanks for the answer Stefan. One thing I don't get though - when you mention 'I would use the bean data source that has distinct load/save events you can use', but say no managed beans, how do you bind the bean to the page then? <\bit confused>

Comment: A object data source is not a managed bean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274765/xpages-extensions-library-and-object-data-source-usage. I called it bean source since you follow bean conventions for get/set.

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought the only way to instantiate a bean which I can use as a data source was through managed bean. I'm not sure how I can make sure that the bean is loaded with information though.

Comment: You do something like var myBean = new com.acme.MyBean(session, database); return myBean; So your constructor has parameters. From the session you get the user, so you know what to query

Comment: If you want sessionCaching and your session bean is sessionCache you would do return sessionCache.getDataBean(session, database); just make sure not to cache Domino objects

Comment: Stephan, if I could ask another question whilst I'm at it: Where would you put the initialisation code for a bean (the code that loads everything into Hashmaps for later consumption): In the constructor of the bean, or in a event such as beforePageLoad, or another place?

Comment: Constructor as outlined in the comments before